# Big sample size (n>50.000), but still highly skewed. Is central limit theorem still valid?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, central-limit-theorem

I have 12 samples with approx. 50.000 data points each. I got it from a content analysis of Reddit comments. The data is generated by analyzing the comments with LIWC tool and it gives me information for instance about the percentage of pronouns in a comment. The comments represent one year and consists of every publicly availabe comment on Reddit for five particular subreddits.

Central limit theorem says that with a certain amount of samples, the data will be normally distributed. This is also the info I got when asking friends, who are quite good in statistics (Master in econometrics etc), when i asked if i can compare groups with the t-test. But when i plot the data, it looks quite skewed and not normal at all and I wonder when you are not able to accept central limit theorem anymore?

How can I be sure that the attributes of the population is not naturally, non-normal distributed?

Comment: (1) See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898 for a similar question.  (2) This is not at all what the CLT says.  Before proceeding, you might want to review it.  Discussions can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=CLT).

Comment: Can you show us a plot of your data distribition?

Answer (score 1):

Confirming Whuber's comment, this is not what the central limit theorem says.  The distribution does not get less skewed as the sample size increases.  All you get is a more and more accurate picture of the shape of the true distribution in the population (just as you get a more accurate estimate of the mean, the SD, etc).

What the central limit theorem says (amongst other things) is that the *sampling distribution of the mean* gets closer to normal as the sample size gets bigger.  This sampling distribution is the distribution of means of the samples; in other words if you took lots of samples of 50,000 items, and plotted the means of those samples as a new distribution in their own right, that histogram would tend to normality, regardless of the distribution of the original means.  It is this that allows you to carry out a t-test regardless of the normality of the original distribution - when the sample size is large enough - and there can surely be no doubt that 50,000 is going to be 'large enough' in this context. [Note: I clarified "of the mean" in the first sentence and added "surely" in the final sentence after reading comments on my answer.]

Comment: (+1) Nitpick, but I think it's important.  The *sampling distribution* is, I believe, the distribution of the samples themselves, i.e. the distribution of datasets of some size, where each datapoint is drawn independently from the base distribution.  It is the *sampling distribution of the mean* which, as you describe, the central limit theorem applies to.

Comment: Re "can be no doubt": although your conclusion is likely correct, I would urge some moderation of that certainty in light of the data analyzed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898.  If one were to interpret the present question generously and constructively, one might be inclined to offer suggestions about how to verify whether your conclusion is true.

Comment: You mean to say "the sampling distribution of the mean", not just "the sampling distribution". Any statistic has a sampling distribution