# proper sample size for the central limit theorem to hold

Tags: sample-size, central-limit-theorem

I have tested the central limit theorem with 1000 samples and a sample size of 4. The resulting distribution was nowhere near normal, and when I used n = 30, it did start looking normal.

Is there a theoretical basis for this "rule of thumb"?

The resulting distribution looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Comment: I took a distribution which was not normal, sampled from it 1000 times a sample of 4, and plotted the distribution.

Comment: What was the distribution?

Comment: And what was the non-normal distribution that you used to sample from?

Comment: It was a bimodal distrubution quite similar to the one I posted

Comment: There is no simple answer to this question. For some distributions the convergence is very fast, but likewise it is easy to make examples where millions of observations will not be enough. Si is often answered (maybe with simulation) on a case-wise basis.

Comment: Some relevant Qs: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61798/example-of-distribution-where-large-sample-size-is-necessary-for-central-limit-t,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/what-references-should-be-cited-to-support-using-30-as-a-large-enough-sample-siz,    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228816/big-sample-size-n50-000-but-still-highly-skewed-is-central-limit-theorem-st,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370445/question-on-central-limit-theorem