# right skewed sample does not lead to normally shaped sampling distributions

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, sampling-distribution

I will provide R code for a reproducible example. I am calculating the difference in means for two groups. I get a sampling distribution by permutations but instead of a normally shaped distribution centered at 0 I am getting this. Can someone explain why? or suggest some change in R code?

***** some further details:

These groups are test and control groups..(2 is a test group) , `x` is amount.

An external provider of marketing software calculates incremental deposit (and other amounts and counts). It calculates statistical significance for difference in means among participants who reacted to the campaign and statistical significance for difference in proportions of participants who reacted to the campaign. And at the end it has a different formula for calculation of increment based on whether both, one or none (diffs in means,props) are significant.

Within my company they want me to reproduce the calculation to put in into a reporting tool. But within this software they say they use Bayesian Monte Carlo with no further info (except conf level 90%) But in Monte Carlo you have to model distribution of variables and I don't know how they do it because it is automated for campaigns ranging from few 10s participants to 1000s and for summing and counting variables. So my lay opinion is that it is a very non-scientific approach. I am trying to come up with a method to do inference find out statistical significance and it should be generalizable for the lack of better term to all campaigns coming.

I am far from an expert here...but thanks for the answers and comments.

[image: sampling distirbution of difference in means]

```
 library(infer)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
x<-structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("C", 
                                  "R"), class = "factor"), amount = c(1000, 500, 1200, 36700, 1500, 
                         1500, 500, 1500, 2500, 300, 500, 2500, 1400, 3050, 1098, 2000, 
                         2156, 1885.78, 1000, 500, 200, 5000, 200, 500, 1100, 500, 1000, 
                         100, 1500, 2370, 1470, 500, 1000, 500, 1200, 21000, 12000, 11000, 
                         7350, 6000, 350, 500, 1700, 400, 500, 500, 2000, 1500, 300, 2600, 
                         100, 480, 3900, 1500, 2650, 600, 900, 4100, 1980, 300, 2300, 
                         200, 54000, 600, 9000, 5000, 100, 300, 323, 500, 2000, 200, 2709.42, 
                         2000, 550, 500, 1800, 300, 6000, 500, 2000, 1911, 5700)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                       -83L))

permuted<-x%>% 
  specify(amount~group) %>% 
  hypothesize(null="independence") %>% 
  generate(reps=15000,type="permute")%>% 
  calculate(stat='diff in means',order=c("R", "C"))
  
  ggplot(permuted,aes(x=stat))+
    geom_histogram()
```

Comment: There is no reason to suppose any particular sampling distribution ought to be Normal.  Many people invoke the CLT but fail to check whether the conditions for applying it are true.  For an extreme example, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898.

Comment: Data in the two groups are moderately skewed with $S_1 \approx 1500$ in `1L` and severely skewed with $S_2 \approx 8770$ in `2L`. Are you are trying to do a permutation test? The two groups are not exchangeable and so my understanding is that a permutation test is inappropriate. // Separate crude quantile 95% nonparametric CIs for the two population means overlap. Roughly, $(1200,2400)$ and $(1850, 6300),$ respectively.

Comment: @BruceET I am curious about how you ascertained the groups are not exchangeable and what you mean by that.  Isn't exchangeability part of the null hypothesis of a permutation test?  Also, what are your $S_i$? They obviously are not skewness coefficients.  Maybe raw or central third moments?

Comment: The $S_i$ are sample standard deviations. I don't make a habit of quoting Wikipedia as an authority, but its page on permutation tests says "An important assumption behind a permutation test is that the observations are exchangeable under the null hypothesis. An important consequence of this assumption is that tests of difference in location (like a permutation t-test) require equal variance." I have seen similar pronouncements elsewhere, but couldn't quickly find another source. If I've misunderstood something fundamental here, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @whuber: Also, tried nonparametric bootstrap CIs for difference in group pop means. Some include 0 (just barely) and some don't (just barely). I didn't mention that in previous Comment because I have not done much bootstrapping with markedly skewed data and wonder whether styles of bootstrap I tried are reliable for these data.

Comment: @Bruce Thank you for the explanations: now your thinking is more evident.  I believe you implicitly assume the alternative hypothesis is that a pure shift in location exists between the groups, but if the alternative is relaxed to permit a shift in location and spread, then why can't a permutation test be applied?

Comment: @whuber. Thanks much. That makes sense. Suspect mean may be or may be entangled with scale.

Comment: I have given an answer for your specific data, but please see [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898/t-test-on-highly-skewed-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a more comprehensive discussion about skewed distributions.

Comment: so I edited the question to give more context of the problem

Answer (score 3):

This graph is perhaps complementary to those of @BruceET. It seems natural to me to work on logarithmic scale for such data. Here the values for two groups as plotted as

1. Quantile plots, each a plot of values against rank. This shows just about all the detail, including ties.
2. Box plots, showing medians and quartiles, but with whiskers extending to the extremes. Given #1, no need to apply arbitrary recipes about other whiskers and what does/does not deserve plotting beyond. (John Tukey's life and work inspired me, but he really wouldn't insist that we follow every darned detail in his 1977 book all the time.)
3. Horizontal reference lines, here at the geometric means. Some may want to recall as a standard result that in a lognormal the geometric mean and the median are equal, which can happen or be approximated in other distributions too, naturally.

[image]

I suggest that focusing on difference in level, however that is summarized, can be over-done. The difference in spread seems as or more important. How far is it a side-effect of sample size?

The habit of anonymising data with names like `x` seems perverse to me. My wild guess is that these are self-reported economic data, with capricious rounding. Telling us what they are would allow subject-matter experts to draw upon experience in suggesting how they might be analysed.

The graph was drawn in Stata using `stripplot` (SSC).

Comment: Thanks for this discussion.

Comment: so I edited the question to give more context of the problem

Comment: Thanks. Given your details, I don't qualify as a subject-matter expert.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your data in a format I found convenient:

```
x=c(1000, 500, 1200, 36700, 1500, 
    1500, 500, 1500, 2500, 300, 500, 
    2500, 1400, 3050, 1098, 2000, 
    2156, 1885.78, 1000, 500, 200, 
    5000, 200, 500, 1100, 500, 1000, 
    100, 1500, 2370, 1470, 500, 1000, 
    500, 1200, 21000, 12000, 11000, 
    7350, 6000, 350, 500, 1700, 400, 
    500, 500, 2000, 1500, 300, 2600, 
    100, 480, 3900, 1500, 2650, 600, 
    900, 4100, 1980, 300, 2300, 200, 
    54000, 600, 9000, 5000, 100, 300, 
    323, 500, 2000, 200, 2709.42, 2000, 
    550, 500, 1800, 300, 6000, 500, 
    2000, 1911, 5700)
gp = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
       2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Here are boxplots of the two samples.

```
boxplot(x ~ g, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
```

[image]

ECDF plots show that neither sample stochastically dominates the other. [There are
very many ties, so it does not seem worthwhile using a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for differences in distribution.]

```
 plot(ecdf(x[gp==1]), col="blue", main="ECDFs of Samples 1 (blue) and 2")
 lines(ecdf(x[gp==2]), col="brown", pch="o")
```

[image]

The two samples appear to come from populations of different shapes, but a two-sample
Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test finds no difference in location.

```
wilcox.test(x ~ gp)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x by gp
W = 767, p-value = 0.5556
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Using the test statistic of the two-sample Welch t test as metric, but not
assuming it has a t distribution, I did a permutation test as shown below,
which also shows no significant difference in location between the two samples (P-value $0.13).$
[In R, `sample`, without extra parameters permutes, the order of elements of its argument.]

```
t.obs = t.test(x ~ gp)$stat
set.seed(2020)
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test(x~sample(gp))$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm)>=abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.12895
```

The histogram below shows the permutation distribution of Welch's t
statistic $T.$ The two-sided P-value is the area in the histogram in the
two tails outside the vertical lines. [If a t test were appropriate, one
would expect the permutation distribution to have nearly a t distribution, which
is not true here.]

```
hist(t.prm, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="Permutation Dist'n")
pm = c(-1,1); abline(v = pm*t.obs, col="red")
```

[image]

**Addendum,** prompted in part by @NickCox's suggestion to look at logs.
Just looking at the plots of the data, it seems clear that the two groups
do not come from the same population. Here are boxplots of the logged data.

[image]

Both groups pass Shapiro-Wilk tests for normality. (Perhaps the original
data were lognormal.)

```
shapiro.test(log(x[g==1]))$p.val
[1] 0.2722435
shapiro.test(log(x[g==2]))$p.val
[1] 0.1087541
```

Then, for logged samples, a standard F-test for equal variances rejects.

```
var.test(log(x)~g)$p.val
[1] 0.01847246
```