# Poor Coverage for Bootstrap Confidence Interval on Mean

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, skewness, coverage-probability

Based on a highly skewed population, I was hoping to obtain good coverage with bootstrap (vs standard) confidence intervals.  I’m not having much luck.

I specify my population in R as a Gamma distribution with shape = 0.3 and scale = 0.5.  I think it’s easiest to see the skew of this population with a graph of its CDF:

```
plot(1:1000/1000, pgamma(1:1000/1000, shape = 0.3, scale = 0.5), 
     type = "l", yaxs = "i", xaxs = "i", xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), col = "red", 
     xlab = "Value", ylab = "CDF", main = "Population CDF")
```

[image: CDF of Population]

Note that the true mean for this gamma distribution is a function of its parameters: $0.3\times0.5 = 0.15$.

In each of 10,000 simulations, I sample 24 values from this distribution.  In each simulation, I calculate the sample mean.  I also calculate a standard confidence interval (based on assumed normality) and three bootstrap confidence intervals (using the boot package in R).  For each simulation, I determine whether the true mean is within the confidence interval for each method.  Note that these simulations took my computer about 25 minutes to run.

```
library(boot)
set.seed(1776)
(trueMean <- 0.3*0.5)

mean.boot <- function(x, i) mean(x[i]) #To be used with boot package for bootstrapping 

sampSize <- 24
numSims <- 10000
bootstrapIterations <- 10000
resultsDF <- data.frame(sampMean = numeric(numSims), withinStandard = logical(numSims),
                        withinNorm = logical(numSims), withinPerc = logical(numSims), 
                        withinBca = logical(numSims))

for (i in 1:numSims) {
  temp1 <- rgamma(sampSize, shape = 0.3, scale = 0.5)
  sampMean <- mean(temp1)
  sampVariance <- var(temp1)/sampSize
  standard_low <- sampMean - qt(0.95, sampSize - 1)*sqrt(sampVariance)
  standard_high <- sampMean + qt(0.95, sampSize - 1)*sqrt(sampVariance)
  
  boot1 <- boot(temp1, mean.boot, bootstrapIterations)
  bootCI1 <- boot.ci(boot1, conf = 0.9, type = c("norm", "perc", "bca"))
  normal_low <- bootCI1[[4]][2]
  normal_high <- bootCI1[[4]][3]
  perc_low <- bootCI1[[5]][4]
  perc_high <- bootCI1[[5]][5]
  bca_low <- bootCI1[[6]][4]
  bca_high <- bootCI1[[6]][5]
  
  resultsDF$sampMean[i] <- sampMean
  resultsDF$withinStandard[i] <- standard_low <= trueMean & standard_high >= trueMean
  resultsDF$withinNorm[i] <- normal_low <= trueMean & normal_high >= trueMean
  resultsDF$withinPerc[i] <- perc_low <= trueMean & perc_high >= trueMean
  resultsDF$withinBca[i] <- bca_low <= trueMean & bca_high >= trueMean
  if (i %% 100 == 0) print(paste0("Simulation: ", i))
}
```

Based on the simulations, the following histogram approximates the sampling distribution of the mean.

```
hist(resultsDF$sampMean, breaks = 39, xlim = c(0, 0.4), main = "Approximation of Sampling Distribution",
     xlab = "Sample Mean")
```

[image: Sampling Distribution]

The histogram’s shape is far from normal, so it’s not surprising that the coverage for the standard confidence interval is poor.  Unfortunately, the bootstrap intervals also have poor coverage.

```
mean(resultsDF$withinStandard)
mean(resultsDF$withinNorm)
mean(resultsDF$withinPerc)
mean(resultsDF$withinBca)
```

Specifically, I’m estimating the following coverages for my 90% confidence intervals:

Standard: 0.8314,
Bootstrap Normal: 0.8128,
Bootstrap Percentile: 0.8219,
Bootstrap BCA: 0.8452.

I’m wondering if I’m doing something wrong, or if my data are just too skewed for a sample size of 24?  Was there something I should have known about bootstrapping that would have made it obvious that my results would be poor?  I figured that my results, even if imperfect, would be notably better than the standard results, which actually require a normal sampling distribution.  Also, any guidance on what I can do to improve my results would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One key thing to know about bootstrapping is that its theoretical justification is purely asymptotic: that is, in the limit of large sample sizes.  Samples of a few dozen (or sometimes, even [tens of thousands](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898)) drawn from highly skewed parent distributions usually are not well characterized by asymptotic results. Intuitively, when the inclusion of a single observation in a bootstrap sample can radically change its characteristics, bootstrapping has to be unreliable -- and this condition characterizes extreme skewness.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link.  From a practical point of view, we just get one sample.  Do you know of a rule of thumb for comparing the skewness of the sample with the sample size to determine if a bootstrap interval is likely to be "acceptable" (i.e, low probability of having "inadequate" coverage)?