# Can I remove a single data point if it is changing drastically a Shapiro Wilk test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, shapiro-wilk-test

I'm conducting a hyphotesis test to compare the mean of two independent samples.
To do so, I need to check normality of both samples.

I have two samples of size 20.
A single data point, on both samples, are making the test statistics to reject the null hyphotesis of normality.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll bring statistics about one sample only, since the other one is very similar (a single data point too far from the center)

So, let me bring numbers:
The p-value of Shapiro Wilk test is 0.642 in the first sample, **removing the "outlier"** data point. Thus, we cannot reject the hyphotesis of normality.
[image: Without the data point]

But, **the original sample does contain this data point**, and then we're rejecting the null hypothesis of normality with a p-value of 0.027[image: With the original data point]

I'm not sure if I can call them outliers and remove, since there is no evidence to support that, the process that generate this data was very similar and nothing so evident would explain this "outlier". Probably something intrinsic to the process.

Can I simply remove this and proceed with my hyphotesis test assuming both samples are normally distributed? Or should I change my test approach?

Comment: if the outlier is intrinsic to the process, then it is important not to remove it. otherwise, you aren't testing the normality of any real world process, you are just playing the game of finding a dataset which passes a normality test. my advice would be to go ahead and conduct the two sample mean test, both with and without the outlier. You may also wish to conduct a similar test on medians.

Comment: ah, wait: these samples don't happen to be paired, do they?

Comment: No, they arent paired. Even though the normality test in the original samples reject the null hypoteshis should I proceed with the mean test? Wouldn't it go against it's assumptions? I did it, and the mean test (I'm using Welchs t-test) does reject the null hyphotesis of equality.

Comment: Yes, there is a violation of normality assumptions. It is unclear *a priori* the extent to which this violation would actually impinge on the veracity of the p-value associated with that test. So I would suggest conducting four tests, based on combining two factors: 1) including the outlier vs excluding it 2) t-test (test on means) vs signed rank test (test on medians). If these are all significant, happy days. If only some subset are, this tells us which aspects of our conclusions are contingent on which of our assumptions.

Comment: You are asking the question in the wrong way.  The issue in your application isn't whether the samples appear Normally distributed: it's whether any apparent departures from Normality would cause you to doubt calculations, like p-values, that have their theoretical support in distributional assumptions.  Thus, formal testing of Normality is unnecessary and it's inappropriate to identify data as outlying solely on considering the empirical distribution.

Comment: whuber, I agree that my question could be better elaborate. I'll pay attention to it next time. Thankyou for this feedback.
Regarding the signed rank test, is it suitable for independent samples? I lack of knowledge about non-parametric tests, so based on my research I found out that maybe sum rank test would be better appropriate, since my samples aren't paired, isn't it? [wilcoxon-signed-ranks-test](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/wilcoxon-signed-ranks-test). Because there is no logical pairs to match up. Nonetheless, thank you for your considerations folks

Comment: Tests based on ranks do not compare means (unless you also assume the null distribution is symmetric).  If these plots indeed show the data in your two groups, you are perfectly fine with a Student t test.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why that's fine to use a Student t-test, based on these qqplots? My sample size isn't enough to consider it following a normal distribution accordingly to CLT, right? Or could you provide some references, then?

Comment: The CLT doesn't apply.  I base this assessment (that the t test will be fine) on experience.  For details of how you might go about analyzing the situation when there's stronger evidence of potential problems, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898.  If you would like to investigate further, you can find [several thousand related posts here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t+test+normal*+distrib*).

Comment: Understood, I really appreciate your contribution. I'll deep dive into these reference links