# How to know if I have enough sample for a small sample t-test to be appropriate?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, sampling, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, small-sample

Say I have 15 or 20 samples each from two samples. The data shows evidence of strong skew.

I am considering a two-sample t-test of means, based on the assumption that the sampling distribution of the mean is t-distributed.

My test is based on pooled sample variance, comparison of means against a null hypothesis of no difference.

$t^*=\dfrac{\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2-0}{s_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}$

How do I know that I have enough degrees of freedom to make this assumption valid?

Of course, some talk about a 30-sample threshold for the t and normal distributions being exchangeable.

But how do we know the t is appropriate? Given modern computation, should we not just use the permutation test or a Mann-Whitney?

What assumptions can I check before considering my choice of test?

Comment: Usually skewness makes the test less powerful than you might think.  To find out how much, you could emulate the study I presented at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69967/919.

Comment: I would assume _no_ test is valid. But that is a conclusion I'm jumping to and I'm not sure how to validate it empirically. @whuber

Comment: I suppose simulation is one idea but that assumes we know moments of the sampling distribution or at least an approximation

Comment: You state you're asking about a two-sample t-test (per your first and third sentences) but the formula for $T_A$ that yo gave relates to a one sample statistic. It matters which you're asking about (the null distribution for the one-sample test is more impacted by skewness than the two sample test). Please clarify.

Comment: @Glen_b I was too quick to copy that. I updated. Two samples, test of means.

Comment: The n=30 “rule” is a joke when asymmetry is present.  And the original question implies that there is something wrong with using the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test if the data happen to be Gaussian.  There isn’t.

Comment: @FrankHarrell That seems a bit harsh as a reply. I'm in no way critical of the technique. I'm just asking how to know if I should use it or the t-test given limited information about the data generating process.

Comment: Fair enough.  I would not rely on large sample theory to make the decision.  When the variable is asymmetric the SD is not a good measure of dispersion and I have an example where N=50,000 is insufficient for achieving adequate confidence interval coverage.