Hypothesis Testing vs Confidence Intervals for sample size calculation
Suppose we're auditing a low-risk group historically showing a mean tax evasion of \$7,883 with a standard deviation of \$27,274 upon auditing. I aim to determine if the average evasion is close to zero. Using a t-test with the null hypothesis that the average evasion is zero (two-sided, $\alpha = 0.05$, power = 0.8), the required sample sizes are 96 for a two-sided test and 76 for a one-sided test. I have assumed that the mean and standard deviation under the alternate hypothesis are what the historical data shows.
However, if I calculate using the confidence interval $\bar{x} \pm 1.96 * \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ and set the lower bound to nearly zero, solving for $n$ gives a sample size of 46.
Is it valid to use a sample size of 46 to determine whether zero falls within the confidence interval, thereby negating the need for larger sample sizes suggested by hypothesis testing? If not, why is this approach incorrect?

How is "tax evasion" measured?  Does it have any possibility of being negative?  If not, then as soon as you have a single positive observation, there is almost surely no chance the average is zero!  //  If by any chance a t-test does turn out potentially to be appropriate, you have a bigger issue than sample size: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898.

The answer from @Michael Lew is perfectly valid; you have a very skewed distribution, and hence the assumption of normality (of the sampling distribution of the mean, mind you, as you correctly note) will be challenged. Hence a (large?) grain of caution is in order.
But that is not the reason for the discrepancy between 96 and 46.
The first reason is that your software calculated the sample size for a t-test. But, by using $1.96$ as you did, you did it for a z-test. Hence, part of the discrepancy.
The 2nd reason is that the way you used the CI gives you only 50% power. You used the observed statistics (mean and sd), and these have only 50% chance (i.e., there is a 50% chance that the true parameter is larger, and 50% that it is smaller; so you have 50% power). This 2nd reason is in fact responsible for most of the discrepancy.
So there are 2 issues with the method. 1) it uses the z critical value, not t 2) it gives you 50% power, not 80%. None have anything to do with the CI approach per se (CI and p-values are flip sides of the same coin; you can think of the CI as the set of parameter values for which $p \ge \alpha$.
Bottom line; you definitively should use 96 (because 46 is plain wrong for what you are trying to do). But even 96 may not be valid, because, as pointed out by @Michael Lew, your distribution is very skewed, CLT may not be enough to help you.  If you absolutely need to do this analysis, I would pick an even larger sample size (large enough to get 10's of non-zero values), and try bootstrapping.

I am not sure if its a t vs z-test issue because isn't the t-table value for N greater than 40 at 95% confidence around 2? I guess I am trying to understand how these two approaches are conceptually different. For example, the one sample test has a notion of power but the CI approach doesn't. And, I am not sure if the two methods are interchangeable or not. Under ideal circumstances is the CI approach valid? Or is there a theoretical reason to never go with the CI approach and always do the hypothesis test?

The only conceptual difference is that 1 is a z-test, the other a t-test. CI and the p-value are flip sides of the same coin (the CI is the set of parameters $\mu$ for which the p value is > \alpha$.  But the other problem is that you calculatiopn for the z-test is for 50% power, not 95% (you are simply using the observed values, w/o any allowance for variability. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Thank you. In general then should we not use the CI approach because of the power issue you outlined (giving 50% power vs 80%)? I think what you are suggesting is that while CI test works ex-post sample collection and measuring the mean, generating an $n$ using the CI approach ex-ante through a sample estimate is wrong because it doesn't capture Type-II error properly. Is this correct?

I would agree with your last comment; that is correct. But I have a hunch -just a hunch! would need to at least run some simulations- that if you took the CI approach, not with the observed means, but with the bounds of the 80% CI of the estimate of the mean, you would get a correct result. Maybe...

This answer overlooks the elephant in the room: 96 will be far too small, because the underlying distribution is so skewed that likely a sample size exceeding tens of thousands would be necessary for any t-test-related calculations to produce anything like a reliable value of significance or power.

@whuber, my last paragraph stated "* But even 96 may not be valid, because, as pointed out by Michael Lew, your distribution is very skewed*",  and added "I would pick an even larger sample size (large enough to get 10's of non-zero values), and try bootstrapping.".  So, I may not have screamed ELEPHANT! loud enough, but I owuld not say that I ignored it?

I read it as screaming "large mouse!" ;-).  It's unclear how one would apply bootstrapping to computing a sample size.  Would you mean exploring possible sample sizes, generating synthetic skewed data sets, and bootstrapping them all?

@whuber, "large mouse!" or maybe "big rat!"? Wrt bootstrapping, my suggestion was about using bootstrap instead of a t-test (because of skew). The sample size recommendation was just "get it large enough so non-zero datapoints number in the 10's": i.e. the non-zero data would be somehow representative, and one would get as many zero's with it as the true distribution dictates. Then the estimates of the mean, and its CI may be better than those from a t-test.

If the mean is 7000 and standard deviation is 27000 and there can be no values below zero then the distribution has to be very skewed. (We know that the distribution of incomes is skewed, so a skewed distribution of evasion amounts is to be expected.)
The mean of a strongly skewed distribution can be a bit misleading, and in this case it is probably much higher than the median, and the modal value is probably zero. The low median and modal values should suffice to allow you to say that the "average evasion is close to zero".
The particular calculation of confidence interval that you are contemplating fails badly with a skewed distribution, so don't use it.

But isn't the distribution of the sample mean i.e. the sampling distribution normal? So using the central limit theorem, this is the confidence interval which 95 times out of 100 should contain the population mean? Thank you for responding.

If I had a sample of 46 value and found that most of them are zero then I would not bother with hypothesis testing. Will that not be the case for a sample from a "low risk group"? If not then the group would not be what I would call low risk.

I see - so you would recommend going with the sample size of 96 from the one mean t-test power calculation?

Two things for you to consider. First, how 'expensive' is an observation? If not very then a larger sample is sensible. Second, given that you already know that the mean value of evasion is greater than zero (one evader in the population is enough) then you do not need a t-test to conclude that the mean value is greater than zero. You want to characterise the distribution, not the mean of the distribution. You often need a larger sample to do that than you need for a reasonably powered t-test, but it depends on the nature of the distribution.

Is your historical data based on samples, or is that actually population data? If it is population data, why don't you believe $7,883. Since tax evasion will never be negative, why do you think it should be closer to 0 than the historical data?

@jginestet due to improvements in the system since the time of the historical data

@MichaelLew  I guess I am trying to understand how these two approaches are conceptually different. For example, the one sample test has a notion of power but the CI approach doesn't. And, I am not sure if the two methods are interchangeable or not. Under ideal circumstances is the CI approach valid? Or is there a theoretical reason to never go with the CI approach and always do the hypothesis test?

The power properties of a hypothesis test and a frequentist confidence interval are the same where the boundary of the interval is treated as the boundary of a critical region, as you want to do. The different results you have may be due to different numbers of tails, but I'm not sure. But I am sure that a hypothesis test will not give you a useful type of inference for this problem!
